# Correct way to attach an item selected listener with a spinner in a fragment attached with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-spinner

I have 4 fragments attached with a viewpager. The 1st fragment has a spinner that has an `item selected listener` in `onCreateView()` method. Each time an item is picked from the spinner, a list adds that data.

Now when I swipe right to get to the other fragments, the 1st fragment is paused. Then if I come back to the 1st fragment the `onCreateView()` method runs again and loads the `item selected listener` again and adds the previosly added data again.

To avoid the situation I've taken the `item selected listener` inside an `on touch listener`. Now It's working as expected. But it just does not feel right. Any advice or help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this like this:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4); // 4 used for number of fragments like you are using 4 fragments using viewpager.
```

This `setOffscreenPageLimit` will not refresh your fragment again and again.